# Breaking out of ice?

Tags: phantasy-star-online

When your character gets frozen, is there anything you can do to break out faster?

I read that you should move the analog stick in a specific way, for example in a [thread on pso-world.com](http://www.pso-world.com/forums/showthread.php?t=89916):

> One of the little tricks from PSO was that when you were frozen, if you wiggled the analogue stick left to right to left to right (etc.) repeatedly you broke out quicker.

**Does this really work?**

If yes, does it also work when catched by Vol Opt’s "green orb" or any other similar effect?

And when playing with a keyboard (PSO Blue Burst), would I just have to press <kbd>←</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ice: yes, moving the analog stick is a quick way to get out of ice. (I also mashed buttons, not sure if that helped)

Vol Opt's trap: No, the only way to be freed is for someone not trapped to attack the trap or for the boss to finish his attack (breaking the trap and causing a lot of damage)

Any other effect: No, the ice is the only effect that you can break out of.

Blue Burst: If those keys are mapped to left/right then yes, that should break you out of ice quicker.